# PHP PDO mySQL query returns column names and integers

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

My PDO query of the database returns unnecessary values into the array.

```
Array
(
    [contentID] => 9
    [0] => 9
    [type] => operations
    [1] => operations
    [type_alts] => pages
    [2] => pages
    [url] => ctt-partners
    [3] => ctt-partners
    [title] => CTT Partners
    [4] => CTT Partners
    [subtitle] => 
    [5] => 
    [online] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [access] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [req] => 0
    [8] => 0
```

)

I am after the array not returning the identical integer fields as well as the names. For example `[0] => 9, [1] => operations`. I don't want these as well.

Why are they here and how can I get rid of them.

Thanks,

Comment: And what's your fetch type? can we see your fetch statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current fetch type must be :

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Whereas for your requirement, it should be:

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set

**fetch_style**

> Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH).

[Reference:](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Answer (score 2):

So just force PDO to do that ...

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(...);
    $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM foo');

    foreach ($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM foo', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
        ...
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // error handling
}
```

Just have a look at the different PDO fetch modes.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation of [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php):

The first parameter defines how the next row will be returned to the caller. There are pre-defined constants available:

> ◦ PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as
>   returned in your result set
>
> ◦ PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set
>
> ...
>   
>   — http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetch.php

You probably call the function with `FETCH_BOTH` or without any argument which defaults to `FETCH_BOTH`.

Change the fetch type to `FETCH_ASSOC`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this because I need that returns a JSON file:

```
 $conn = new PDO("...","...","...");
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
 $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```